# .NET/ASP.NET vs Java on ADVANCED Features

Tags: c#, java, .net, visual-studio

Most comparisons I can read on the internet are about the syntax whereas it doesn't matter much. I care more about advanced features. For example, I read on .NET about these features:

- Partial Class .Net support not java [java partial classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501736/java-partial-classes)
- Adaptive Control Behavior http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67276kc5.aspx
- Parallel Class http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.aspx
- Solver Foundation http://www.solverfoundation.com/
- Reverse Enginiering with UML Sequence Diagram http://blogs.msdn.com/b/habibh/archive/2009/07/29/use-uml-sequence-diagrams-in-team-system-2010-to-reverse-engineer-your-code.aspx
- MS-CAPI (Microsoft Crypto API) certified FIPS 140-1 compliant http://groovy.codehaus.org/Bridging+the+Gap+Between+Java+and+.NET+with+Groovy+and+Scriptom

These are features I would need for future projects maintenance. Currently we use Java and I can't really find any equivalence of them on java platform or can you point me towards them that are free and well integrated (not having to hack to make things work smoothly - like using another 3rd language to wrap calls -  or pay 10000$ more to get the feature) ?

Answer (score 1):

In terms of language "advanced" features and "power", I generally find: Java << C#3 (.NET) << Scala. (Although C#/CLR does have things not present in Scala.)

I'm not even sure why ASP.NET is in the title though. You also throw VS into the confusion. It's just a (popular ^^) C# IDE.

As far as "need"? Well, there are a million Java projects and libraries. They just don't always act the same way as the C#/CLR (or Scala) counterparts. It doesn't mean you *can't* do it in Java.

Comment: Visual Studio is an IDE, ASP.NET is not an IDE it's like J2EE platform. I put ASP.NET because Adaptive Control Behavior concerns ASP.NET not .NET alone.

Comment: There are "millions" yes but how many has professional mainteance, support, documentation etc. that is enterprise ready ?

Comment: Scala is a functional language like F# and as far as I can see could also be deployed on .NET though it doesn't seem to be focused on it which is a pity.