# enum in separate class

Tags: java, enums

Is there anyway to put this test in a separate class? I tried but was unsuccessful.

```
public class TrafficLightprj 
{
    public enum TrafficLight 
    {  
        RED(1),  
        GREEN(2),  
        YELLOW(3);

        private final int duration; 

        TrafficLight(int duration) { 
            this.duration = duration; 
        }  

        public int getDuration() { 
            return this.duration; 
        } 


        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            for(TrafficLight light: TrafficLight.values())
            {
               System.out.println("The traffic light value is: " +light);
               System.out.println("The duration of that trafic light value is: " + light.getDuration());
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you try to separate them and fail? You can have an `enum` in its own class file.

Answer (score 15):

I'm not sure I understand what you mean in your question, so I'll answer to what I *think* you are asking.

An enum can be its own file in Java. For example, you could have a file called *TrafficLight* which, inside, is:

```
public enum TrafficLight {  
    RED(1),  
    GREEN(2),  
    YELLOW(3);

    private final int duration; 

    TrafficLight(int duration) { 
        this.duration = duration; 
    }  

    public int getDuration() { 
        return this.duration; 
    } 
}
```

You then can use this enum from your test project (*TrafficLightPrj.java*). Like so:

```
public class TrafficLightprj {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(TrafficLight light: TrafficLight.values()) {
            System.out.println("The traffic light value is: " +light);
            System.out.println("The duration of that trafic light value is: " +light.getDuration());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to put it in a different .java file itself. You can't have more than one public class / enum in a single .java file.

**TrafficLightprj.java**

```
public class TrafficLightprj {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(TrafficLight light: TrafficLight.values()){
            System.out.println("The traffic light value is: " +light);
            System.out.println("The duration of that trafic light value is: "  +light.getDuration());
        }
    }
}
```

**TrafficLight.java**

```
public enum TrafficLight {  
    RED(1),  
    GREEN(2),  
    YELLOW(3);

    private final int duration; 

    TrafficLight(int duration) { 
        this.duration = duration; 
    }  

    public int getDuration() { 
        return this.duration; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, but you need to qualify the enum class name. `TrafficLightprj.TrafficLight` instead of `TrafficLight`. Or, I guess, import it.

I am not a big fan of non-private nested classes, and suggest making the enum top-level.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your question is: *"How to get a [nested enum](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html) in a different source file?"*

This would be possible with partial classes, but this [isn't supported in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501736/java-partial-classes/2501812#2501812).

Comment: Seems that I misinterpreted the question, I don't see what's wrong with the answer.

Comment: @Tom Hawtin: It seems the other answers are just neglecting the fact that it's a nested enum. I kind of assumed that was the question, how to get a nested enum in a different source file.

Comment: I think it's about getting the "test" code into a separate file. Who knows?